# Accessing FILESTREAM share by a user on another domain with full trust

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I have a FILESTREAM share on a SQL server in domain AAA and a users in domain AAA and BBB.   The two domains have a full trust.  Users in domain AAA can access the share from UNC \server\mssqlserver\dbshare\tableshare or through Explore FileTable in SSMS.  Users in domain BBB can't access the share through the UNC or SSMS. However they can map a network drive to the share and access it that way.  Both users have same login/user permssions on the instance/database. Why cant users in domain BBB access the share through the UNC path or SSMS?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Mapping a network drive involves using a UNC, FYI.

Comment: Are BBB users having the network drives mapped using the credentials of another user (perhaps a AAA domain user)? (That's the only way it makes sense that they can access via mapped drive but not via UNC, and it would be an important clue to get confirmed.)

Comment: @MaxVernon - standard error for UNC path click: Windows cannot access \\... and Explore FileTable in SSMS returns : The File location cannot be opened. Either access is not enabled or you do not have permissions for the same. However I know the user has a login/user with appropriate permission. Yes I know mapping a network drive involves a UNC, that's why its odd clicking the UNC path fails and mapping the UNC works. T.H - BBB user is mapping the drive using their BBB credentials.

Comment: Not sure if accessing the share through the domain trust makes it a memory resident file.  I've read FILESTREAM can have problems with that and mapping the share as a network drive can fix it.

Comment: Use this link http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to get your two accounts merged.